# Android App Downloads N APK's From PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, web-crawler

Is it possible to download any number of apks onto an external storage from an Android app? I want to download certified Android apps from the Play Store for analysis purpose.

I've thought about writing a web crawler that would use the Play Store as the root URL. The PlayStore however downloads and installs all APKS straight to the device. There is also no Google Play Store API that would take care of the authentication.

I thought it would be fun to write an app that would do the same and download all the apks and store them in the external storage instead of the /downloads.

Any tips, leads or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: My tip is: hire qualified legal counsel and discuss your plans with this person.

Comment: lmao that is a fair tip.